# Spark streaming mapWithState does not work

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I would like to play with mapWithState function in Spark Streaming,the version is Spark 1.6, Scala 2.10.

Here is part of my code:

```
def updateState(batchTime: Time, key: String, value: Option[String], state: State[Double]): Option[(String, Double)] = {
  val sum = state.getOption.getOrElse(0.0) + 1.0
  val output = (key, sum)
  state.update(sum)
  println("current state: "+state.get().toString())
  Some(output)
}
val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(updateState _)
  .numPartitions(2)
  .timeout(Seconds(60))
```

Every time I run this, the current state would be always 1.

I am pretty new to Spark Streaming, if you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: What input data are you providing? Are you actually providing multiple values for the same key?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  Oh, I didn't realized that before, my key is a random IP address. After changing the key, it works now, thank you!!!

Comment: You welcome. :)